# Select query optimization with multi-column index

Tags: c++, sqlite

A query is taking long time to execute. This is my table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable(
    Id int primary key,
    column1 text ,
    column2 text,
    column3 text,
    column4 BLOB
);
```

There are around 160,000 rows in the table.

I also have a covering index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX index1 ON mytable(column1 ,column2 ,column3 ,column4);
```

I use 2 select queries:

```sql
SELECT column4 from mytable;

SELECT column4 from mytable where column3="xyz";
```

that take 0.101722 and 0.136498 seconds to execute, respectively.

These are the pragmas I enabled:

```c
sqlite3_exec(db, "PRAGMA auto_vacuum = 1", NULL, NULL, &zErrMsg);
sqlite3_exec(db, "PRAGMA page_size = 32768", NULL, NULL, &zErrMsg);
sqlite3_exec(db, "VACUUM", NULL, NULL, &zErrMsg);
sqlite3_exec(db, "PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY", NULL, NULL, &zErrMsg);
sqlite3_exec(db, "PRAGMA synchronous = OFF", NULL, NULL, &zErrMsg);
sqlite3_exec(db, "PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF", NULL, NULL, &zErrMsg);
sqlite3_exec(db, "PRAGMA cache_size = 15000", NULL, NULL, &zErrMsg);
```

Is there any other way I can speed up the execution?

I am using sqlite api for c++ on an unix machine.

Answer (score 2):

With index constructed as such:

```sql
CREATE INDEX index1 ON mytable(column1 ,column2 ,column3 ,column4);
```

you are actually performing **indexless search**. Multicolumn indexes in sqlite work from left to right only.

If you have a query that filters only on `column3` you have to have an index which starts with `column3`. Like this:

```sql
CREATE INDEX index1 ON mytable(column3);
```

Details on this mechanism can be found in chapter [1.6 in query planning](https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html).

Comment: yes..i had 2 indexes .But with that my second select is taking still more time. around 0.275114 seconds.so i reverted to single index.

Comment: as you said it wont be a indexless search.EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN shows Covering index being used